# JSON Response Formatted Odd

Tags: json, .net-5

I would appreciate help if possible with this.  I've come to expect JSON payloads in a particular format and I do not yet know why it's not returning as such.

The payload is including fields for $id and $values

for example this is the response I'm getting

(this is .Net 5)

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$values": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "baseId": "1daa8e1b-11c4-eb11-8f57-9408532f1cc6",
            "productDesc": "wreath",
            "price": 41,
            "imgUrl": "wreath1.jpg",
            "laborInvoledMin": 240,
            "descr1": "wreath1",
            "descr2": "wreath",
            "descr3": "wreath",
            "descr4": "wreath",
            "createdOn": "2021-06-02T22:12:13.077",
            "tblDetails": {
                "$id": "3",
                "$values": [
                    {
                        "$id": "4",
                        "detailId": "1eaa8e1b-11c4-eb11-8f57-9408532f1cc6",
                        "baseid": "1daa8e1b-11c4-eb11-8f57-9408532f1cc6",
                        "price": 10,
                        "imgUrl": "wreath1.jpg",
                        "laborInvolvedMin": 1,
                        "descr1": "wreath",
                        "descr2": "",
                        "descr3": "",
                        "descr4": "",
                        "createdOn": "2021-06-02T22:12:20.52",
                        "base": {
                            "$ref": "2"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm expecting is effectively what's in the $values bracket

Controller:

```
namespace x.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]

    public class productsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private productsContext _ctxt;

        public productsController(productsContext ctxt){
            _ctxt = ctxt;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<TblProductBase>>> getDetail()
        {
            List<TblProductBase> tblProduct = await _ctxt.TblProductBases
                .Include(i => i.TblDetails)
                .ToListAsync();
            
            return tblProduct.Any() ? Ok(tblProduct) : NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

models

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace x.Models.products
{
    public partial class TblDetail
    {
        public Guid DetailId { get; set; }
        public Guid Baseid { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
        public int? LaborInvolvedMin { get; set; }
        public string Descr1 { get; set; }
        public string Descr2 { get; set; }
        public string Descr3 { get; set; }
        public string Descr4 { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public TblProductBase Base { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace x.Models.products
{
    public partial class TblProductBase
    {
        public TblProductBase()
        {
            TblDetails = new HashSet<TblDetail>();
        }

        public Guid BaseId { get; set; }
        public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
        public int? LaborInvoledMin { get; set; }
        public string Descr1 { get; set; }
        public string Descr2 { get; set; }
        public string Descr3 { get; set; }
        public string Descr4 { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TblDetail> TblDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

context

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using x.Models.products;

namespace x.Data
{
    public partial class productsContext : DbContext
    {
        public productsContext()
        {
        }

        public productsContext(DbContextOptions<productsContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<TblDetail> TblDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TblProductBase> TblProductBases { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("x");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");

            modelBuilder.Entity<TblDetail>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.DetailId)
                    .HasName("pk_TblProductDetail_DetailId");

                entity.ToTable("tblDetail", "products");

                entity.Property(e => e.DetailId)
                    .HasColumnName("detailId")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(newsequentialid())");

                entity.Property(e => e.Baseid).HasColumnName("baseid");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("createdOn");

                entity.Property(e => e.Descr1).HasColumnName("descr1");

                entity.Property(e => e.Descr2).HasColumnName("descr2");

                entity.Property(e => e.Descr3).HasColumnName("descr3");

                entity.Property(e => e.Descr4).HasColumnName("descr4");

                entity.Property(e => e.ImgUrl).HasColumnName("imgUrl");

                entity.Property(e => e.LaborInvolvedMin).HasColumnName("laborInvolvedMin");

                entity.Property(e => e.Price)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 0)")
                    .HasColumnName("price");

                // entity.HasOne(d => d.Base)
                //     .WithMany(p => p.TblDetails)
                //     .HasForeignKey(d => d.Baseid)
                //     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                //     .HasConstraintName("fk_TblProductDetail_TblProductBase_BaseId");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TblProductBase>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.BaseId)
                    .HasName("pk_TblProductBase_BaseId");

                entity.ToTable("tblProductBase", "products");

                entity.Property(e => e.BaseId)
                    .HasColumnName("baseId")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(newsequentialid())");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("createdOn");

                entity.Property(e => e.Descr1).HasColumnName("descr1");

                entity.Property(e => e.Descr2).HasColumnName("descr2");

                entity.Property(e => e.Descr3).HasColumnName("descr3");

                entity.Property(e => e.Descr4).HasColumnName("descr4");

                entity.Property(e => e.ImgUrl).HasColumnName("imgUrl");

                entity.Property(e => e.LaborInvoledMin).HasColumnName("laborInvoledMin");

                entity.Property(e => e.Price)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 0)")
                    .HasColumnName("price");

                entity.Property(e => e.ProductDesc)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(250)
                    .HasColumnName("productDesc");
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I should note I am using ReferenceHandler.Preserve to handle an reference issue

Comment: have you tried returning `JsonResult` in your controllers? Something like `public async Task<JsonResult> getDetail()`

Comment: Hi Andy.  I gave it a try but it returned the same.  I'm wondering though if it has anything to do that my tables use guids for primary keys

Comment: public async Task<JsonResult> getDetail()
        {
            List<TblProductBase> tblProduct = await _ctxt.TblProductBases
                .Include(i => i.TblDetails)
                .ToListAsync();
            
            return Json(tblProduct);//.Any() ? Ok(tblProduct) : NotFound();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because my use of using System.Text.Json.Serialization; in the startup to utilize ReferenceHandler.Preserve for a looping issue - that I'm still not sure I fully understand

Regardless - removing this resolves the issue